# Candy Crush Saga Type countdown life system jQuery & Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I'm developing an app and I'm interested in ways to achive a Candy Crush Saga Type countdown life system. 
My app is developed in phonegap (so html, css jquery and jquery mobile) and untill now I havn't figured out how to work with an external file as I'm thinking it's needed in this algorithm.
I want therefore to have 5 lives and each of them dissapears when the user fail or quit the lvl and regenerates after, lets say, 10 minutes. How can I keep the counter active if the app is closed?
Or a date substraction algorithm...

If somebody have knowledge in Phonegap I would be very grateful if he could help me with a jsfiddle wich I'll implement further in my app.

I'm also not sure what to use: localstorage vs DB

I'll give 50 of my bounty for the one who can help me with a jsfiddle example for this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Doubt its a good idea to store "lifes" on a loca, manipulateable storage. Especially when you think about having an online leaderbord/competition among people - which most games happen to be about.. I'd recommend you to do a small server backend (NodeJS would be fine), that will save and return the lifes of a player. Whenever somebody starts a level, load the level data from server so people loose a life everytime they start a level. For regeneration, save a timestamp and if on any request last life was given > 10 minutes ago, add 1-5 accordingly to how much time have passed since.

Comment: @user1610743 Well the game isn't online.. As in candy crush when I start a lvl a life is put in the game and if I loose the life is lost if I pass the lvl and I reach the next one the life stays the same. I'm also not sure what to use: localstorage vs DB? The part with the timestamp is good but what if I lost 3 of the total 5 lifes and while I'm playing the second one the 3'rd must regenerate and than the 4'th and than the 5'th if I dont loose. If I loose also the second one is lost... I'm new to jquerry, phonegap and I'm lost. If you have more knowledge can you please post a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code I use the `localStorage` since they are available on all platforms and web.
Using local storage you will get better cross platform compatibility:

- [WebStorage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) (localStorage & sessionStorage)
- [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)
- [SQL-Storage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage)

Localstorage is array, but every element can only have string in it (using JSON we can store anything, that is not recursive). It is about 5MB for web. I guess it is limitless for mobile app. SessionStorage is deleted when user close browser and I am not sure how it will do on mobile.

Just a small date validator...

```
Date.prototype.isValid = function(first_argument) {
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(this) !== "[object Date]" )
        return false;
    return !isNaN(this.getTime());
}
```

The main var declaration among retrieving variables from localStorage

```
var timeout = null;
var maxlife = 5;
if (undefined === localStorage.life) {
    localStorage.life = maxlife;
}
if (undefined === localStorage.date||localStorage.date=="") {
    localStorage.date = "";
    var date = null;
}else{
    var date = new Date(Number(localStorage.date));
    if(!date.isValid()){
        date = null;
    }
}
var timeoutTime = 5 * 60000;
var life = Number(localStorage.life);
```

Lose life, set date if none exist yet. Set a timeout too and subtract life (& write it into localstorage).

```
function loseLife() {
    if (null === date) {
        date = new Date();
        localStorage.date = date.getTime();
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime);
    }
    life--;
    localStorage.life = life;
    lives.innerHTML = life;
    console.log(life);
}
```

Add life, set date new date or reset the date completely. Set a timeout, if needed, and add a life (& write it into localstorage).

```
function addLife() {
    life++;
    localStorage.life = life;
    if (life < maxlife) {
        date = new Date();
    localStorage.date = date.getTime();
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime);
    } else {
        date = null;
    localStorage.date = "";
    }
    lives.innerHTML = life;
}
```

Here you may need to change the hooks for blur (window not visible) and focus (window  visible once again). Blur just clear timeout so it don't mess with us.

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

This function check how many time it can subtract our time needed to get life from difference of now and the date we lost a life.

```
function tillNow(){
    if (life < maxlife&&date!=null) {
        var d = new Date();
        var diff = d - date;
        while (diff - timeoutTime > 0) {
            diff = diff - timeoutTime;
            if (life < maxlife) {
                life++;
                console.log("add");
            }else{
                date = null;
                localStorage.date = "";
                break;
            }
        }
        localStorage.life = life;
        if (life < maxlife) {
            date = new Date((new Date()).getTime()-diff);
            localStorage.date = date.getTime();
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime-diff);
        }
    }
    lives.innerHTML = life;
}
```

Focus just call tillNow()

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    tillNow();
});
```

Onload do the same as focus, but fills the div with a value initially...

```
window.onload=function(){
    var lives = document.getElementById("lives");
    lives.innerHTML = life;
    tillNow();
}
```

[Demo](https://student.sps-prosek.cz/~eisead11it/web/IS/Administrace/index.html) sorry couldn't do jsFiddle of codepen since they don't like local storage. (the demo use 15sec as timer to get new life ;) I am impatient )

Comment: hey man! I tried to implement the script in my app and as I feared it's not working 100% correct. When I close the app the regeneration of the lives isn;t workig anymore. Aslo if I minimise the app and go back to it sometimes it adds unnecesarry lifes even if the 15 se arn't over... I implemented the whole script in the deviceready... Is it allright? May you please assist me a little bit? this is my current app with your script... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89068397/android.rar

Comment: I remember to do some changes to the code, if you copy the js that is in the demo you will have for sure the latest version, I might forget to mirror it here, please let me know,if it works if you copied the JS from web to your app. I don't have android, and I am not home now

Comment: its still not working with the latest version. I made some tests the whole day today to figure exact what's the problem but it very strange. So if I enter in the app everything works fine (they regenerate as they should) If I remove lives till 0 and I close the app and reenter it the number is still 0. If I press again on the button it's -1 and nothing regenerates. In this moment if I minimize the app and I reenter it the lives are set as if the initial "counter" were working but if  press again on the button they still dont regenerate. I have to minimize and maximize a few times to work

Comment: I was testing it on my phone and also on ripple emulator and the effects were pretty much the same. I also noticed something like those bugs on your demo too but I dont know what is causing them. What I could find out is that sometimes the lifes and the date in the local storage (and also in the interface) dont get updated untill I click the button. And whan I do that sometimes they start regenerating, sometimes not. It's very strange. When you're home please take a look at my code. Maybe I havent included the functions you provided correctly. And You can also test it on rippe without android.

Comment: I may found it... there was && at place of || what wac causing to regenerate all lives. It is on line 145 in your code. I couldn't find any other bug, but if you do, tell me.

Comment: Well there's still a bug: I consume 5 lives (for example) and when I exit the app and wait untill the lives may be regenerated and I stard the app the lives are still 0. It also happends on phone and in ripple. The lives from the local storage are not updated and I can see that the date is not existent! In that moment if I press only once the button to decrease lifes, the lifes decreases and start regenerating as usual till they reach 5. I don't know why the date from localstorage gets deleted when I close the app. I guess that's the problem...

Comment: Ok I stayed today the whole day to to find the bug and this is a detailed "debugging" process as I've done. I pulled on each step the fresh localstorage db from the device:
1) I cleared the localstorage and I entered the app, I killed some lives and they regenerated ok. 
2) I left the app with all the 5 lives active and I closed it
3) after 1 sec I reopened it and I saw that the data from localstorage was empty
4) When I press the remove live button the lifes decreases but NO DATA was stored in the localstorage!!! and no lifes are regenerating

Comment: 5) If I wait 5*15 sec (the time in wich all the lives shoud have been regenerated while this, the current life state is 0 in the app and also in the localstorage) or if I minimise the app and maximize and I PRESS AGAIN the button, a date is stored in the localstorage, the current lives are set to 4 and the lives begin to regenerate normally untill they reach 5.

I don't know why the date isn't stored if I reenter the app and I press the button. That might be the issue.

Otherwise everything is working fine if I dont close the app...

Comment: I retried the process but befor closing the app I decreased the lives till 0, I wanted to see if the data remains stored in the localstorage but after I close the app and I reenter the app nothing is stored into data. I have to press once the button, the lives decreases and only after that something appears into data and the lives start regenerating... Other things like my lvl remain stores in the localstorage.. only the data dont... I still don't get it...

Comment: As it seems there may be few bugs in webStorage: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-189213.html?s=f16d7d12eda5954f8349e6358153998b This might do the trick, but I am not sure, however if you are not able to reproduce those bugs in my demo, it have to be on Android side...

Comment: The thing is that the localstorage works perfectly for my lvl feature and for the lives. It only dont work with the date parameter as it doesn't store it when I close the app. I found simmilar issues within the demo you provided. If I loose all the lives till they reach 0 and I close and open the tab several times they stop regenerating and the date and the lives parameter arn't also updated... Just try to close the tab and open it several times within the regeneration process and you'll notice it..

Comment: I just entered now again on your demo and the lives were set to 5 and when I pressed the button they decreased but nothing was stored into the date!! Exactly the same what happened in my phonegap application!! So I guess it's nothing with phonegap... just a bug in the actual script... Please let me know as soon as you can if you can fix it.. I stayed for over a week for this feature and it's driving me crazy -_-

Comment: I got the steps that I made when the date wasn't saving: 1) enter the demo, clear the localstorage from chrome developer tools 2) ctrl+f5 3) close the tab 4) reopen he tab and click on the button ... You'll notice that the lifes are decreasing but nothing is stored in the date  field!! I think this is the problem.

Comment: Same line as last time, the != was changed to == . The date was saving, but as a empty string. Number("")==0 and this was causing the problem. It was then creating date as 1970 and it was regenerating all lifes you lost, once you closed and reopened the page.

Comment: I changed the line into this:     if (undefined === localStorage.date || localStorage.date=="") {   I guess that is what you meant before... And now the date remains stored if I close the app.

Comment: there's one more single bug here.. I saw that in youe axample the lives and the date from the localstorage and from the <div> aren't always updating, sometimes only if I click once somewhere on the screen. This happends also in my phonegap app but there it doesn't update if I click on screen, it updates only if I click once on the remove lives button wich isn't ok at all. Is there any way to update them all the time when I am on that page?

Comment: For example in my app when i remove all lives and then I enter agin in the app (after lets say 15*5 seconds) the lives in the localstorage and the date are the same as old time. Whan I click once on the button, lives==4 and the date is the new date. I still dont get it why the localstorage values aren't updating only on another stimulus..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51532/discussion-between-akxe-and-alex-stanese)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Sorry this is some pseudo code based off PHP - but you don't need crazy algorithms or anything

I don't write phone apps, but I know what you're trying to do and you're thinking about it too hard. You don't need to run the counter while the app is closed. You can save a timestamp from when the game is over, and reference it the next time the app is opened.

```
start_game();

if($lives > 0){ //run game
    if($death === true){
        $lives = $lives - 1;
        $timer_value = date(Y-m-d h:i:s);
        end_game($timer_value); //save starting time locally in "end_game" function
    }

} else {
    //buy more lives
}
```

Now let's say the user closes it and opens up. You can reference the current time versus the saved time. For every 10 minutes past then, add a life.

```
$old_time = strtotime($timer_value); //635393400
$cur_time = strtotime(date(Y-m-d h:i:s)); //635394600

if( $cur_time - $old time > 600 ) { $lives = $lives + 1; }
if( $cur_time - $old time > 1200 ) { $lives = $lives + 2; }
if( $cur_time - $old time > 1800 ) { $lives = $lives + 3; }
if( $cur_time - $old time > 2400 ) { $lives = $lives + 4; }
if( $cur_time - $old time > 3000 ) { $lives = $lives + 5; }
if( $lives > 5 ) { $lives = 5; }
```

That's some awful code lol, but you gut the idea. You don't need to run a timer in the background (you can't really with the app being closed, without doing some sort of server checks online, which is basically the same thing, but hosting all that personal life records in the cloud instead of on the phone.

Comment: but for example the 5 livee should regenerate also if I'm currently playing on the 4'ts and the game isn't over yet. SO they should regenrerate alos if I don't close the app. The regeneration should start in the moment I lost a life. Aand about the if's you told me for example if I loose t lifes and the currnt time is 1200 there will be added 3 lifes because it goes also in the first if > 600 wich isn;t the case I wanted. And another question what about the storage? Wich should I use? localstorage or DB? So actually the whole life experience should be identically with candy crush.

Answer (score 2):

I would use logic similar to what Xhynk suggested. I would use a variable like milisecondsUntilYouGainALife and when you lose the first life, set this variable = 1000ms*60sec*10min = 600000. Then first line (or so) in main loop, record the current time. next time it hits the loop also record the time and subtract the difference from milisecondsUntilYouGainALife. If < 0, lives++. Also make sure in your "close the app" function you record the time and check that time in the main loop.

pseudocode:

```
function game(){
    ...
    while(mainLoop){
         oldTime = curTime
         curTime = GetTime() //I Forget the exact code to get the miliseconds
         deltaTime = curTime - oldTime
         if(deltaTime > milisectionsUntilYouGainALife){
            if(lives < MAX_LIVES){
                lives++
                milisecondsUntilYouGainALife - deltaTime
             }
          }

    }
}
function AppClosing(){
    curTime = GetTime()
 }
function LoseALife(){ 
    milisecondsUntilYouGainALife += 600000
}
```

There may be something im missing, but this should get you on the right track!